# Making a list of tuples with sequential elements in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

Assuming `K an integer number`, `Y a pd.Dataframe()` and `Z a list()`. How can I make a list of tuples with the following sequential structure for the first element of each tuple:

`[(K,Y,Z), (K+1,Y,Z), (K+2,Y,Z), (K+3,Y,Z), (K+4,Y,Z),......,(K+N,Y,Z)]` , for any positive value of `N`.

Comment: Did you try a list comprehension?

Comment: do you actually want to include the whole `Y` dataframe and `Z` list in *each* tuple ?

Comment: @diogeek Yes please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python uses 0-based indexing by default. Therefore, if you actually want your counter to go from `1` to `N`, in python you'll have to specify it. otherwise it'll go from `0` to `N-1`, which is the exact same number of iterations, but it will not return the same numbers.

You can use a `for loop`:

```py
final_list :
for ii in range (1,N+1):
    final_list.append((K+ii, Y, Z))
```

Or if you're looking for something a little fancier, use list comprehension :

```py
final_list = [(K+ii, Y, Z) for ii in range (1,N+1)]
```

Although I'd advise against it if you can't read it as easily. Readability counts, and it's not worth the trouble if you can't understand it afterwards.